# ¿Cómo hacer que un audio se reproduzca al mismo tiempo que se ejecuta un diálogo de alerta?

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando hacer un programa en JavaScript que al pulsar el botón *Enter*, llama a una función que activa un dialogo de confirmación, pero a la vez yo quisiera que se escuche al mismo tiempo que aparece la alerta un audio que especifiqué para que se reprodujera

Y la verdad es que no lo he logrado, el audio se reproduce después de que le doy click al botón *ok* o *cancelar*, pero yo quiero que suene el audio al mismo tiempo que sale la ventana de confirmación.

**Código**

```
shortcut.add("Enter", function () {   
    confirm("¿Desea comensar el juego?");
    let sonido = document.querySelector("audio");
    sonido.setAttribute("src", "audios games/pruevaAudio06.mp3");
    sonido.play();
});
```

> **PD:** Uso una librería de atajos de teclado llamada **Shortcut**.

Comment: Todo modal del tipo `confirm`, `prompt` o `alert`, es bloqueante. Por lo cual tu código quedará suspendido o pausado hasta que se cierre el modal. Te sugiero usar otra estrategia para lograr lo que te propones. Saludos

Comment: Hola Mauricio, muchas gracias de verdad por responder a mi pregunta, la verdad es que no lo sabía, pero lo que yo quiero lograr es hacer un programa para dar al usuario un mensaje de voz mientras que aparezca un tipo de ventana, y que me recomendarían en este caso. ¿Pero no existirá alguna manera parecida de lograr algo así?